# Android change play/pause button icon when clicked

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

Honestly, I do not know why, but any solution for same problem I have as already on stackoverflow is not working for me 
I am trying to have play/pause buttons switched when clicked, when playing my stream for my radio station.

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Currently it is separate, because many of my attempts failed.

**main.xml** (many call it activity main)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/pause" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MusicAndroidActivity.java**

```
    package clever.radio;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import static android.R.attr.id;

    public class MusicAndroidActivity extends Activity {

        static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        Button buttonPlay;
        Button buttonStop;
        String url = "http://radioclever.stream:8000/stream";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
            });

            buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
            buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mPlayer.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="clever.radio"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MusicAndroidActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace two buttons by a button. I name it is bt_play_pause. Then, add two images to the Resource folder, they are pause.png and start.png, may be. And take a look on my code. Hope it can help you.

> main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_start_pause"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/play"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> MusicAndroidActivity.java

```
public class MusicAndroidActivity extends Activity {

    static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Button bt_start_pause;
    boolean paused = true;
    String url = "http://radioclever.stream:8000/stream";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bt_start_pause= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_start_pause);
        bt_start_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.start); bt_start_pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(paused){
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mPlayer.start();
                paused = false;
                bt_start_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                //when MediaPlayer stared, pause button is shown
                }
                else{
                if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    paused = true;
                    bt_start_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
                   //when MediaPlayer paused, startbutton is shown
                }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, except i have no idea how to do that and where to put this code. I am totally beginner in this.

Comment: I already have that images. play.png and pause.png in drawable. 

I just need code for main.xml and what to replace in my .java file so it can work.

Your code wont help

Comment: I tried with this using your code

`boolean paused = true;
iv_start_and_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(paused){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            iv_start_and_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            paused = false;
        }
        else if(!paused){
            mediaPlayper.pause();
            iv_start_and_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
            paused = true;
        }
    }
});`

Comment: Ok. i get Cant resolve method setImageResource

can i put SetBackgroundResource instead?

Comment: I forgot it. Yeah, you can try to use setImageResource. But in my opinion, use should use ImageView like a Button if you want to set the image for it. You can setOnClick for the ImageView as a Button. Nothing is changed.   [link]https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types

Comment: I combined your answer with @devmike and it works! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8OmLeYJgV7KMWVwNlRib29iUTA/view?usp=drivesdk check it out

Comment: Please to help you @LukaPreazic

Answer (score 1):

Change `<Button...` to `<ImageButton`...
Your xml now should look like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_or_pause"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and reference to it in your java code by doing this

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play_or_pause)
...
if ( mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
    // When MediaPlayer paused, start button is shown
    mPlayer.stop();
    paused = true;
    imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
} else {
    // When MediaPlayer started, pause button is shown
    imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
}
```

Comment: You realize I have no idea where to put this?

Comment: This answer is the most accurate because without changing the Button tag to ImageButton, you can never display an image button. Also, i copied the above codes from yours and modified it...

Comment: I know that, but before you, another answer provided whole code, i just replaced button with image button as you suggested.